# Lower incomplete gamma function

Tags: gamma-function

From Wikipedia,

The upper incomplete gamma function defined as:

$$\Gamma(s,x) = \int_{x}^{\infty}t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$

whereas the lower incomplete gamma function is defined as

$$\gamma(s,x) = \int_{0}^{x}t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt.$$

My question is that can we write the following equation. How can we write or is there any reference

$$\gamma(s + 1,x) = \int_{0}^{x}t^{s}e^{-t}dt.$$

Thanks in advance:

Comment: Yes, this is fine since $s$ is just a constant. If you wish, you can write
$$\gamma(z,x) = \int_{0}^{x}t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt.$$
and then take $z=s+1$.

Comment: Thank you so much